# Getting a microphone to work on a Mac Mini

Tags: macos, mac, microphone, mac-mini

I just bought a new microphone, and plugged it into the back of my Mac Mini. I can't seem to get it to work. I went to System Preferences > Sound > Input, and the only device I see listed is "line in." This isn't the microphone, is it? Nothing I do seems to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd think "Line In" is the correct device (if you plugged into  "audio in", second from top-right: http://images.apple.com/macmini/images/features_portdiagram_20091020.jpg). Not sure how to make it work though... I'm testing the same thing with my Mac mini and a headset. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mac Mini's line-in port is a line-level input.  That means it's not providing any power to the device, so an unpowered computer mic is not going to work.  You need something to pull the mic-level input of the mic up to line-level, like a mixer or certain types of powered mics.

Alternatively, you can use something like [the iMic](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/imic/), or any USB mic/headset from Logitech, etc.  If your Mac Mini is a model with Bluetooth support, you could also use a Bluetooth mic.

Comment: Great answer. I for one was totally unaware of this.

Comment: Just bought the iMic, but beware, there is a 1/4 second delay if using using speaker for output. I was using it for singing and guitar playing and this letancy renders iMic useless.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution to that unpowered linein.

We can use a mic(rophone) app on android/ios phones and then connect the phone to the {line in} input jack using an Aux cable.

Its so Easy as ABC.