# How do I install a microphone on a Mac Mini using iMic Griffin?

Tags: microphone, mac-mini

As other users before me, I have the problem of getting a microphone to work on a Mac Mini.

See for example:

[Getting a microphone to work on a Mac Mini](https://superuser.com/questions/102803/getting-a-microphone-to-work-on-a-mac-mini)

One suggested option was the use of a USB device like iMic Griffin.

Now, I have an iMic Griffin, and I am pretty sure that everything is plugged in correctly and that the setup is fine, because the audio of my headset works fine and the blue bars on the sound property site visually react to sound from the microphone.

But when I try to use the mic with Skype, it doesn't work. (It is unlikely that Skype or the headset are at fault, because they work together on another computer.)

Do you have suggestions where the problem might lie? I would also be happy if you point out another Mac program that can be used to test the microphone.

My computer's data:

Processor: 2,3 GHz Intel Core i5
Software: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

Comment: go into skype's preferences and then audio settings, and make sure that your USB griffin microphone is selected as the mic.

Comment: @AlanTuring Thanks, that was it. I didn't think of it because I never had to change the settings on the other computer. Please feel free to delete this question as you deem appropriate.

Comment: hi i will paste my comment in the answer, please accept it as an answer, i'm glad it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into skype's preferences and then audio settings, and make sure that your USB griffin microphone is selected as the mic